# Regenerating default overlay in gentoo

Tags: gentoo

Could not sync portage for some time - realizing it was because I was using git as sync method and [the repo was not maintained anymore.](https://github.com/gentoo/gentoo-portage-rsync-mirror) They also provided new links so I updated `sync-uri` option in `/etc/portage/repos.conf/gentoo.conf`

```
[gentoo]
location = /var/db/repos/gentoo
sync-type = git
#sync-uri = https://github.com/gentoo/gentoo-portage-rsync-mirror  # old
sync-uri = https://github.com/gentoo-mirror/gentoo                 # new
auto-sync = true
```

But this was without effect when running `emerge --sync`:

```
# emerge --sync
>>> Syncing repository 'gentoo' into '/var/db/repos/gentoo'...
/usr/bin/git pull
Already up-to-date.
=== Sync completed for gentoo
```

Today I realized that I can check remote url of the repository:

```
# cd /var/db/repos/gentoo
# git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/gentoo/gentoo-portage-rsync-mirror (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/gentoo/gentoo-portage-rsync-mirror (push)
```

So it is still set to the old one.

I tried to change it to the new one, but it was first complaining about git config and even after that I could not sync:

```
# git remote set-url origin https://github.com/gentoo-mirror/gentoo
# git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/gentoo-mirror/gentoo (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/gentoo-mirror/gentoo (push)
# git config user.email "root@gentoo.xxx"
# git config user.name "Root One"

# emerge --sync
>>> Syncing repository 'gentoo' into '/var/db/repos/gentoo'...
/usr/bin/git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/gentoo-mirror/gentoo .
fatal: destination path '.' already exists and is not an empty directory.
!!! git clone error in /var/db/repos/gentoo
!!! Repository 'x-gentoo' is missing masters attribute in '/var/db/repos/gentoo/metadata/layout.conf'
!!! Set 'masters = gentoo' in this file for future compatibility
```

So at the end I ended up with deleting whole directory `/var/db/repos/gentoo` except `distfiles/` with `ls -a | grep -v distfiles | xargs rm -r` which solved my problem and I could finally sync..

Question is: is there some user friendly / right way how to recreate/regenerate gentoo overlay which is using git?

I think more people will have this problem once repository of overlay will be changed.

Comment: To my knowledge only Funtoo uses a github master tree.  A normal gentoo tree is stored at `/usr/portage`, and uses the rsync protocol.  Please manage user created overlays with `layman` and in the event you lose the tree again, use `emerge-webrsync`

Comment: Yes now we can also use git (and [others](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Project:Portage/Sync)). Will check `layman`s capabilities more deeply for now. Thanks for comment.